# Is any extra set up needed to run vscode-r in remote SSH?

Tags: r, visual-studio-code

I've been using the session watcher feature in vscode-R, and it works great locally. I was wondering what sort of special configuration is needed to get it working in a remote environment?

If I just use VSCode's instructions to connect to a remote host using the Remote Extension I can get a remote terminal and start radian, but I don't see the anything in the task bar indicating the R session it's attached to (unlike the local version, which works just like in the documentation). None of the features (e.g. showing plots, documentation, variable completion, etc) work.

Do I need any extra set up in the remote machine? Let me know if more information is needed. Thanks!

Comment: I think the plots aren't showing because they're rendered on the remote machine. you could save the plots as png then download them.

Comment: Check you have the .Rprofile step done: https://github.com/Ikuyadeu/vscode-R#advanced-usage-for-self-managed-r-sessions If it still doesn't work, may be easiest to create an issue at https://github.com/Ikuyadeu/vscode-R/issues and we can do some troubleshooting.